# Print POJO to System.out issue

Tags: java, jaxb

Following some tutorial ([this one](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)) I am not getting same output on console.
The tutorial is about converting Java object to/from XML using JAXB API - JAXBContext, Unmarshaller, Marshaller.

This is POJO code:

```
package com.jaxb.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

This is unmarshalling code:

```
package com.jaxb.example;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class JAXBExampleTestUnmarshall {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        try {
            File file = new File("./jaxb-data/file.xml");

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

            Customer customer = (Customer)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            //System.out.println(customer.getId());
            //System.out.println(customer.getName());
            //System.out.println(customer.getAge());
            System.out.println(customer);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And this is `./jaxb-data/file.xml` file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer id="1">
    <age>33</age>
    <name>Some Name</name>
</customer>
```

I am getting `com.jaxb.example.Customer@15e8d410` when I run this class.

Question: Why am I not getting `Customer [name=Some Name, age=33, id=1]` on output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to overwrite `Customer#toString`, which gets implicitly called when you Sysout an object. The standard implementation is the fully qualified class name and the hexcoded-`hashcode()` of this object.

Comment: I see, `toString()` isn't implemented in tutorial for `Customer` class, so i assumed it should be default behaviour. Obviously not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override `toString()` method for meaningful reprsentation of your object. `System.out.println()` calls `toString()` method and you can see the string returned from `toString()` method.

```
public String toString(){
   return "Customer [name =" + name+ ", age=" + age
            + ",id =" + id "]";
 }
```